# Setting a variable in an exec() that was declared outside the exec() in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

Can someone explain why this doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @PROCESS_TABLE varchar(100) = 'Table Name'
DECLARE @SRIDCount int
EXEC('SELECT ' + @SRIDCount + ' = COUNT(DISTINCT Geom.STSrid) FROM ' + @PROCESS_TABLE + '')
Print @SRIDCount

Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

but this does:

```
DECLARE @PROCESS_TABLE varchar(100) = 'Table Name'
DECLARE @SRIDCount int
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max)

SET @SQLString = 'SELECT @SRIDCount = COUNT(DISTINCT Geom.STSrid) FROM ' + @PROCESS_TABLE + ''
EXECUTE SP_executesql @SQLString, N'@SRIDCount int OUTPUT', @SRIDCount = @SRIDCount OUTPUT
Print @SRIDCount

1
```

Mostly I want to understand why I can't set a variable in an exec(). Using SP_executesql seems cumbersome and complicated by comparison and so far I have gotten away with not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please try avoiding dynamic sql whenever possible. Think about sql injection, readability, error handling, maintainability... There are many reasons to avoid dynamic sql. I claim that your above use case can be solved without the use of dynamic sql.

Next you need to understand that `'SELECT ' + @SRIDCount` is trying to add the value of the @SRIDCount (which is NULL btw) to the leading varchar, not the name of the variable. You could easily fix by adding the variable to the querystring: SELECT `@SRIDCount = COUNT(DISTINCT Geom.STSrid)...`

Your second mistake is to assume that `EXEC()` can interfer with variables outside of the inner batch, which is treated as an own transaction and has no access to your declared variables.

Your example provided using `SP_executesql` is also an enclosed transaction, by specifying the output you are able to use the result of the query.

Rewriting your first query would work if you include the variables within:

```
DECLARE @PROCESS_TABLE VARCHAR(100) = QUOTENAME('Table Name')
EXEC(N'DECLARE @SRIDCount INT
SELECT @SRIDCount = COUNT(DISTINCT Geom.STSrid) 
FROM ' + @PROCESS_TABLE + '
PRINT @SRIDCount')
```

But I assume you want to work with the count in a further query. So following workaround should do the job:

```
DECLARE @PROCESS_TABLE VARCHAR(100) = 'Table Name'
DECLARE @SRID TABLE (SRIDCount int)
DECLARE @SRIDCount INT

INSERT @SRID
INSERT INTO @SRID
EXEC(N'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Geom.STSrid) 
FROM ' + @PROCESS_TABLE )

SELECT @SRIDCount = SRIDCount 
FROM @SRID
```

But, like I stated in the beginning, rethink about what you try to achieve and how you could do it without dynamic sql.

Comment: I'm using dynamic sql because this is a part of a significantly larger script that will need to be run on different tables and databases. Not sure if there is an easier way to replace 50 table name calls in a script. I'm not worried about injection because this isn't going to the web or really outside my team. The readability and error handling does suck though. I do understand that the way I had @SRIDCount set up in the first query was incorrect syntax but I couldn't think of a better way to show what I was trying to get at.

Comment: I definitely have a better understanding of how SQL batches work thanks to everyone's responses. Thanks for the workaround example @Raul

Comment: Actually the workaround doesn't appear to populate @SRID with anything so SRIDCount remains _null_

Comment: Glad you learned something new. This is what stackoverflow is here for, exchanging knowledge.

Comment: I hurried and messed up the second exec query by leaving the variable within, which is not needed. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @PROCESS_TABLE varchar(100) = 'Table Name'
DECLARE @SRIDCount int
EXEC('SELECT ' + @SRIDCount + ' = COUNT(DISTINCT Geom.STSrid) FROM ' + @PROCESS_TABLE + '')
Print @SRIDCount

Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

1. Since you haven't assigned a value to SRIDCount, the statement would literally be

   `'SELECT ' + NULL + ' = Count(...'`
2. Concatenating a string and a null results in a Null.  You are in essence trying to run

`Exec (null);`

3. if you were to assign a value to SRIDCount, you will get a data type conversion error because a number cannot be added to a string (string + int + string).  If you convert your SRIDCount to a character datatype, you can substitute properly in the string.  However, that is not likely what you want to do.
4. Exec runs the query in a new batch.  Memory is not shared between batches, the batch within the Exec statement has no visibility to the outer statement.

Try printing your @SRIDCount before you execute it.  Once your printed statement looks good, add the Execute statement and run again.  If you include the Exec before you've validated your statement, you are risking running a query that doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `exec` runs your sql command within a batch and variables do not exist outside it's own batch.

#### [execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

> Executes a command string or character string within a Transact-SQL
> batch...

#### [variable scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_0)

> The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that
> can reference the variable. The scope of a variable **lasts from the
> point it is declared until the end of the batch** or stored procedure in
> which it is declared...

Comment: But I can bring variables in like @PROCESS_TABLE to use as table name within a exec() so it can handle variables outside it's own batch to some extent. I guess they just draw the line at setting variables outside the batch?

Comment: @joe - You are not bringing in the variable `@PROCESS_TABLE`, you are creating a string with the value and passing that into the batch. For example: `exec('select @PROCESS_TABLE')` will fail

Answer (score 0):

Note how different you (have to) make `@SRIDCount` work together with the queries:

`'SELECT ' + @SRIDCount + ' = COUNT....'` will concatenate a String `SELECT` with *the **VALUE*** of `@SRIDCount` and `'COUNT ...'`.
As the variable was newly instantiated just one line above you will most probably end up with:

`'SELECT 0 = COUNT ...`

On the other hand the later example is a String that still contains the variables *NAME* and not it's *VALUE* and thus this one works as intended. That is **also** but **not only** because with

`N'@SRIDCount int OUTPUT'`

you explicitly mark this variable as some value you want to be returned from the query.